# How to make Grid View (using Recycle View) with dynamic item width in android?

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

i want to make grid view that has fixed item height but width is dynamic based on content with like screen below
[i want to make it like this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSshD.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a number of items fixed per row [staggeredGridLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) or [GridLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) .

Here is a tutorial for each one:

- [GridLayoutManager](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/)
- [staggeredGridLayoutManager](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

Select the one acording your needs, good luck.

[EDIT]

You could try [this widget](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) if you need to fill a row with the number of elements that fits on screen

Comment: i want to make width dynamic ?

Comment: For that you will have to measure the elements and add them programatically checking if adding the new element won't be larger than screen. You could also try this widget : https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Comment: Did you tryed with staggeredGridLayout? i think you can use it to fill your needs.